# IBM BluemixのAlchemy API、分析可能な画像サイズに上限ありますか？

Tags: bluemix

IBMのPaaS 「Bluemix」でアプリ開発をしているものです。

BluemixのWatsonカテゴリーにあるAlchemy APIで画像を認識させようとしたところ、ファイルサイズの上限と思われるErrorとなりました。分析可能な画像のサイズに上限はあるのでしょうか？

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy APIのこちらの[Image TaggingのAPIの説明](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/image-tagging/image.html)を見ると、処理可能な写真の上限は1MBのようです。

> Requested image documents **can be a maximum of 1 megabyte**. Larger documents will result in a "content-exceeds-size-limit" error response.